# Getting Exception while executing Basic Script to open a Browser

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting Exception while Executing Basic Login Script using Selenium 
I have installed Geckodriver version 1.6 And Java 8 version also i installed 3.4 selenium Jar files.

**Here is The Code**

```
package started;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DemoLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\AKULA\\Desktop\\geckodriver");

        WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
        dr.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/");
        dr.manage().window().maximize();
        dr.quit();
    }
```

### }

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:

Comment: Can you please include the exception so folks can help you.  You can [edit] using the edit link below the question. Good luck! :)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:5884 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'AKULA-PC', ip: '192.168.43.131', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:

Comment: Akula can you please paste it in the question body so we can read it.  :)

Comment: I Guess problem is here `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\AKULA\\Desktop\\geckodriver");`  mention `geckodriver.exe` here

Comment: @jmort253 hope is it clear now .

Comment: @NarendraRajput,,,Please elaborate What changes should i do..

Comment: You need to write complete path in set properties like `C:\\Users\\AKUL‌​A\\Desktop\\geckodri‌​ver.exe`

Comment: @NarendraRajput i changed it ,But now i am getting different Error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\AKULA\Desktop\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe

Comment: Please write the correct folder path of `geckodriver.exe` where it located . suppose E.g. I  have placed it in `D:/driver/geckodriver.exe`

Comment: @NarendraRajput Its not working I tried .

Comment: @AkulaBhaskar Can you update if your program is working now?

Comment: @Dev No Dev ,,Its not..M really unsure where m going wrong

Comment: Can you update the question with your latest code & the error you are observing?

Comment: @Dev     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:7974 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: I tried all things nothing working out ,Still i have been marked negative votes for my questions by smart people around. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK

Do the following steps

1. Download geckodriver (v0.16.1 win 32bit) from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it in your computer `D` driver
2. Now update your firefox  to latest version
3. Download selenium 3.4.0 from here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
   and extract the folder
4. Now create a project in eclipse and add downloaded selenium 
   jar files  project > properties > java build path > switch libraries tab > add external jar files (add all jar files)
5. Now write the below code :

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class TestCls {

   public static  WebDriver driver;
   public static void main(String a[])
   {

   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:/geckodriver.exe");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/");             
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
   }
   ```

Comment: @narenra Rajput can you explain why the following exception comes                 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:22962 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: what is your firefox version ?

Comment: Exception come in case your selenium  version / browser version or exe version not  match

Comment: M using Firfox version 53.2 64 bits and selenium 3.4 and i did installed Geckodriver .But not sure why m getting error.

Comment: install geckodriver mean what ? just place the exe in one folder and give the path . can you paste the code of set property line

Comment: @ Tuks  .
package started;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DemoLogin {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
  
  WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
  dr.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/");
  dr.manage().window().maximize();
  dr.close();
 }
}

Comment: I tried all things nothing working out ,Still i have been marked negative votes for my question.Wonder Why.